# How do I separate my Selenium grid setup and testNG Parameters from my Selenium tests using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

This may be a bit of a noob question, but I am a tester setting up an Automation framework and learning as I go. I think I would like to house my @Parameters and @BeforeTest separately from my actual test cases. This way, I can use the same parameters for any number of test cases.

See my code below. It's 2 simple methods under a class: one that is purely setup, and could be used across any test, and another that is my test script(I know it's messy, and I will be adding more parameters to the setup method, but what I have now runs in parallel using 2 nodes just fine).

How do I go about putting the setup into it's own file? The below code is all in the same .java file in src/test/java now, but I think the setup method would go into src/main/java or src/test/resources. I would still execute the test with a testng.xml file.

```
public class FrameworkTest {

private WebDriver driver;

@Parameters({"platform", "browser"})
@BeforeTest (alwaysRun=true)

//define configuration variables... String version 
public void setup(String platform, String browser) throws MalformedURLException
{
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

    //Platforms
    if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("windows"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    else if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("WIN8"))
        caps.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);

    //Browsers
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internet explorer"))
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

    else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    //initiate hub's driver
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.2.112:4444/wd/hub"), caps);
     //driver.navigate().to();
}



@Test
public void main() throws InterruptedException {    

//Open webpage
driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.com");
//search
driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("Selenium");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/fieldset/input[3]")).click();
//click on the link to the proper page.
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Selenium (software)")).click();
//verify we are on the correct page
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Selenium (software)"));
}
```

Comment: See "inheritance" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: You may find this useful https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template.  Even if you don't want to use it you can pull it apart and see how it all fits together.